# Where can I get good criticism for my photos?

Tags: image-quality, learning, photo-critique

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to get community-based feedback on my photos online?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2884/where-to-get-community-based-feedback-on-my-photos-online)
>   [How do I give someone a critique of their photograph?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7885/how-do-i-give-someone-a-critique-of-their-photograph)

So one way to learn something and to be good at it is to let others evaluate your work and tell you what they liked and what they don't. There are two types of people who can do this: photographers and non-photographers. Photographers will tell you what's wrong and right in your photo from photography perspective, non-photographers will tell you stuff like "wow amazing colors" or "this is so dark" but they won't talk about shutter speed or aperture cause they probably don't know about these stuff. So where can I get good opinions about my photos (especially from photographers). Are there any online fourms ?

Comment: And also see http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2884/where-to-get-community-based-feedback-on-my-photos-online for online feedback.